# Python 3: Beautifulsoup and cache

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

i use beautifulsoup in Python3 to find a string on a website.
All works fine so far. But if the website changes, it takes some time until my script also finds this change.
I guess there is any kind of cache, which is the problem.

```
    URL = 'https://www.lotto.de/lotto-6aus49/lottozahlen'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).text, "lxml")
    if  not 'Samstag' in soup.find('span', class_='WinningNumbers__date').text:
      print(soup.find('span', class_='WinningNumbers__date').text)
      print('Die Samstagszahlen sind noch nicht online.')
      sys.exit()
```

Am i right with my guessing and how could i change this behaviour?

Comment: do you want to detect the site changed? or you think that your requests are using some kind of cache?

Comment: Im kind of sure that my request uses a cache. The site content changed during 2 runs of the script in 5 minutes, but i still got the same output.

Comment: you'll have to share your code then

Comment: I edited my first post and added the important code of the part which does not work correct.

Answer (score 1):

this has nothing to do with BeautifulSoup, but only with the usage of `requests`. From what I know the library doesn't really use cache by default, which could be enabled installing the external package [`requests-cache`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-cache).

But just in any case, you can always use the `Cache-Control` header:

```
requests.get(URL, headers={'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'})
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try this.